# Use external parameters.json file not working with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, templates, azure-cli

I am trying to pass parameters in via the parameter file in Azure Cli

The script below ignores my file
What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried ParameterTemplateFile as mentioned in another post here but that doesnt work either

```
templateFile="Path\template.json"
parameterFile="Path\parameters.json"

az deployment group create \
  --name <NAME> \
  --resource-group <RESOURCE GROUP>\
  --template-file $templateFile \
  --parameter-file $parameterFile
```

Answer (score 0):

When running via Azure Cli I should have been using @parameters.json